# bad shell auto-created bad account on vps

Tags: cpanel, whm

a bad uploaded script auto creating bad cpanel account on my host. i found and terminate that bad file.

but theres is still bad auto-created account in whm.  (account not showed in GUI WHM )

is there a way to remove them completely from root access?

here the list of the bad whm account 
vfs1.zip
vfs2.zip
vsf3.zip

Comment: i know old hacked created account still there,  (i know cuz i could see them in my backups)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. check `/etc/passwd` to ensure that no malicious users where add or if any of the current users was given shell access, if you found any strange users then here is [what to do](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/143935/148912)
2. Check the server with [RootKitHunter](http://rkhunter.sourceforge.net/)
3. Disable SSH access for root and ensure there are no strange SSH Keys and if possible make SSH only for known IPs
   And don't forget to check the logs either SSH logs e.g /var/log/secure or the web server logs to identify the source as possible.

Also check this question about [how to deal with compromised serve](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)